# Parsing image data from Java inputstream

Tags: javascript

I did a ajax get request and I recieve the below image response.

```
ï¿½PNG

���
IHDR���2���2���?ï¿½ï¿½���gAMA��ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½a��� cHRM��z&��ï¿½ï¿½��ï¿½���ï¿½ï¿½��u0��ï¿½`��:ï¿½��pï¿½ï¿½Q<���bKGD������ï¿½Cï¿½���  pHYs����ï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½��ï¿½IDAThï¿½ï¿½ï¿½yï¿½TÕï¿½?ï¿½Õ«zï¿½ï¿½zï¿½nvï¿½Þ€ï¿½iï¿½Uï¿½AQvï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½D!bï¿½Iï¿½f5ï¿½ï¿½d\"&ï¿½`ï¿½qGï¿½p!ï¿½DYLDï¿½e5ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½+UMu×¾ï¿½ï¿½nï¿½h2gï¿½4Bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½sï¿½;uï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½~Î½ï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½9Nï¿½×‹ï¿½}ï¿½8Sï¿½9ï¿½8'rï¿½qNï¿½lC=S
556rï¿½ï¿½Ajï¿½kØ·ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½6"ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½gdÒ­{W

ï¿½9ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½PPï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ß¯ï¿½ï¿½O>aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½[Wï¿½ï¿½\9Nï¿½ï¿½v2sldï¿½ï¿½pï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½!H(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Zï¿½Å¶jï¿½Kï¿½×ŽSï¿½ï¿½È‘ï¿½ï¿½4iï¿½ï¿½_NNï¿½ï¿½[eï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
Yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"ï¿½Uï¿½SPÖ‡ï¿½ï¿½dfï¿½8ï¿½ï¿½Þ†ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½8\ï¿½ï¿½Ë¦ï¿½ï¿½@ï¿½dLï¿½Ú˜ï¿½fï¿½ï¿½ÍŸyXï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Æ„ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½3yï¿½ï¿½Syï¿½ï¿½gyï¿½ï¿½ï¿½hï¿½)ï¿½<ï¿½ï¿½Q#ï¿½é…ï¿½H"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Cï¿½>ï¿½ï¿½CXGï¿½ï¿½Vï¿½ï¿½atÕ‡Sqï¿½ï¿½jï¿½jNï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½+Ë¥ï¿½ï¿½*ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/~0u:ï¿½yï¿½!zï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½Djkï¿½qëœ›ï¿½hï¿½.Î¿z6ï¿½.ï¿½Djï¿½d+ï¿½#l!hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½"dU   aWï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½!ï¿½hBï¿½iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½q9Ur3uzuwï¿½=ï¿½IVï¿½ï¿½4`ï¿½ï¿½^ï¿½{ï¿½ï¿½Ú“ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½5kï¿½é‹¬ï¿½ï¿½
nï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½rï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½fï¿½n=Hï¿½H=f"ï¿½ï¿½Ä±;ï¿½hZï¿½Ã®Qï¿½�vï¿½j�]ï¿½h6ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½*ï¿½Pï¿½&ï¿½,ï¿½Fï¿½[ï¿½ï¿½o=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Tï¿½/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½p|;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
3f2hï¿½\.ï¿½ï¿½iF$Hï¿½vh7Fï¿½ï¿½.qï¿½Eï¿½H[i?\Ï‘ï¿½Fï¿½GZï¿½GBXfï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½:}2(,È Gï¿½Ru
Fï¿½B
ï¿½Kï¿½ï¿½Wï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Gï¿½4m5Å¥yï¿½ï¿½QUï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0hï¿½Lï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½-ï¿½Ûï¿½ï¿½8tA,pï¿½ï¿½;ï¿½Ò´ï¿½kï¿½4ï¿½E~ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ù³.W*ï¿½b#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½{hko&ï¿½ï¿½oï¿½ï¿½Ñ£zRZï¿½ï¿½]QHï¿½$ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Bï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½h9ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½Q1ï¿½Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½'/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½äŒ¾ï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½ï¿½dØ‡bï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½xï¿½|ï¿½ï¿½Jï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½o_*+ï¿½æŠ±WP\Ü—lwï¿½    ï¿½t,ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½tï¿½ï¿½TU}ï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½k*ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ÈŠ\RSTï¿½}  Tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ÇŸXï¿½ï¿½~ï¿½ï¿½''2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½,ï¿½\Kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`1ï¿½ï¿½bÒºo;Éˆï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½tï¿½nï¿½ï¿½/ï¿½lÌ˜ï¿½se9ï¿½ï¿½
<ï¿½ï¿½i^xï¿½Yï¿½{Gï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\|Q.ï¿½nï¿½m;ï¿½Pï¿½ #ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½{ï¿½"//ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Jï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½-gï¿½ï¿½@ï¿½eï¿½(
ï¿½`ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½g,yï¿½9Vï¿½Zuï¿½�ï¿½{ï¿½bï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½Éï¿½maï¿½f/ï¿½ï¿½QEï¿½(ï¿½Pï¿½`ï¿½e}ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½q"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½t)ï¿½ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½+^"-ï¿½ï¿½ÇŸ|ï¿½
3fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½7)..bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½-lï¿½ÚŠï¿½+ï¿½Hqï¿½hï¿½ï¿½-3Jxï¿½ï¿½eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ELï¿½ï¿½+WR4|ï¿½ @(
ï¿½>"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ZEIIï¿½ï¿½ï¿½+Bï¿½{v!ï¿½^v%ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.CRï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½!nï¿½erï¿½ï¿½%ï¿½&>ï¿½ï¿½iï¿½"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.eXFï¿½hï¿½
f"Nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½]ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½oï¿½\ï¿½[ï¿½�ï¿½7Bï¿½ï¿½T!ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½ï¿½..(Kg×®Ýï¿½456ï¿½\ï¿½Ý°Lï¿½CDQï¿½ï¿½ï¿½DÛ©ï¿½vï¿½w"Ó¬ï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½ï¿½Cï¿½
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½pï¿½"ï¿½a�
BQ=ï¿½:ï¿½aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½;HOK#Nï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½D1
ï¿½ï¿½É„Ñ¹ï¿½Ûï¿½ï¿½I<ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`jilß¶ï¿½;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½BQï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½sw;(ï¿½OwÎ±{ï¿½1"ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Óï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½:J)%g*ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½yï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ddï¿½ï¿½gï¿½ï¿½Sï¿½'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½8vUï¿½foï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|Yï¿½oqï¿½1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½r1zï¿½ï¿½|ï¿½s}GNï¿½<zßˆEï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9ï¿½ï¿½qsfï¿½È’×–ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Mï¿½bï¿½ï¿½ï¿½|]ï¿½ï¿½6_;ï¿½ï¿½Ò­{Wï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½%Vï¿½\Í¼{ï¿½aï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½%W'4ï¿½,ï¿½Ý®ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½4yìŒ¾ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½E�ï¿½ï¿½~&Kï¿½ï¿½ |ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ò‘fï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½D*+Yï¿½ï¿½3ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Rï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½&Ö®Yï¿½[oï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Yï¿½Y
ï¿½iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½d:ï¿½ï¿½1ï¿½'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½'ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½pï¿½ï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½pÇ­1ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Kaï¿½uTï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cGï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½^0ï¿½`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½DQLlï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½Ï¿ï¿½Mï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Pï¿½!ï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½lï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½wWï¿½bï¿½ï¿½Qï¿½
~6ï¿½naÍ’#/ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½o,ï¿½Kï¿½cË¢;v2oï¿½ï¿½lï¿½zï¿½gT0uZï¿½o ï¿½ï¿½T6zØ¼ï¿½Ëï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½ï¿½3fï¿½eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Nkï¿½ï¿½k>dï¿½ï¿½ï¿½\~ï¿½ï¿½8ï¿½dÔï¿½Äˆï¿½+ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mbÓ›ï¿½SzI*&ï¿½Gzï¿½ï¿½+5IZFiï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½HDï¿½)ITGï¿½nï¿½r Æ¢;o:ï¿½ë®½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½^~ï¿½%6lXCNvï¿½;~:ï¿½!ï¿½9Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½#ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½8&ï¿½  ï¿½ï¿½ywï¿½ï¿½ï¿½O<Í•ï¿½^AVï¿½|ï¿½Afï¿½%yï¿½Hk5ï¿½ï¿½ZlDï¿½Vï¿½Jï¿½ï¿½4z8p8ï¿½hzï¿½wï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½eE@&ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½w,ï¿½o?ï¿½Ì¾]!ï¿½4Bï¿½×€  ï¿½ï¿½Ó˜2ï¿½U!ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½L.ï¿½ï¿½ePiB
ï¿½{d[ï¿½ï¿½`Ç¶ï¿½dfe'ï¿½ï¿½)ï¿½Cï¿½<Jss/ï¿½ï¿½5Lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½1ï¿½Qï¿½&   8Rï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½ï¿½$y%Yï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½3ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½BÐ—Ç¤ï¿½ï¿½1biA"fï¿½ï¿½ï¿½6ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½M^ï¿½JS]ï¿½ï¿½M1V/  ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½]ruï¿½ï¿½$;ï¿½jï¿½_aï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½}ï¿½ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½#Ç®B&sfï¿½ï¿½ï¿½7Þ¥bï¿½]ï¿½ì—‡Ú‹ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½mï¿½ï¿½Aï¿½ÑŽ
J(ï¿½*0�gï¿½pï¿½ï¿½nï¿½$1yï¿½ï¿½fTï¿½ï¿½ï¿½C9ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½HHï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½G|ï¿½{%Ä•ï¿½zï¿½5W'5Ù¾ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½POï¿½/_Fyï¿½à¿™ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½zrï¿½ï¿½{qUï¿½ï¿½ï¿½A8S$ï¿½Í<>Bm!bï¿½ï¿½Tï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½$ï¿½ï¿½æ‡»ï¿½ï¿½Ó†ï¿½ï¿½$ï¿½&zï¿½ï¿½0,ï¿½�iA$(ï¿½6X,yï¿½ï¿½Hï¿½BAï¿½ï¿½M[ï¿½;~*ï¿½_|ï¿½ï¿½]ï¿½vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½bï¿½;wï¿½ï¿½\ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Æ”)ï¿½9Pï¿½ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½Q>n(yï¿½ï¿½Hwï¿½qï¿½ï¿½pï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½Mï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½k
ï¿½ï¿½9ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½H@ï¿½oï¿½hï¿½3iï¿½cb$@ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9z1ï¿½oxï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0_$9ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½++Yï¿½q
Wï¿½|2ï¿½9ï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½&?Mï¿½~vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xï¿½Ä•acï¿½ï¿½ï¿½OI#3imLï¿½zqï¿½ feï¿½ï¿½cï¿½Hï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½Î¢&\ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½]ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½tÂ—ï¿½3/YÌ´ï¿½iï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½ï¿½+ï¿½oy.iï¿½ï¿½Lï¿½ï¿½_ï¿½N^?u;ï¿½ï¿½?ï¿½Eï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½GvMï¿½ï¿½E   ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Qï¿½}k^ï¿½rpG
6,<iï¿½ï¿½rï¿½#ï¿½L&Yï¿½pï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Ó¿ï¿½ï¿½È©yï¿½jï¿½x8Jï¿½ï¿½[ï¿½
)MLï¿½@ï¿½P$ï¿½ï¿½!ï¿½RAZï¿½DÌ¢Í›ï¿½Pï¿½A[ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½pï¿½ï¿½qï¿½
ï¿½8ï¿½<ï¿½|dï¿½Mï¿½ï¿½×®gÎœ[ï¿½3=ï¿½^ï¿½:zï¿½ï¿½L&�!,ï¿½ï¿½Dï¿½&ï¿½U~ï¿½ï¿½,Bï¿½ï¿½"l6ï¿½ï¿½:ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½/`ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½.ï¿½ï¿½rxï¿½^ï¿½x<ï¿½tilhï¿½ï¿½gÍ‘ï¿½ï¿½2ï¿½+ï¿½tï¿½*G\å”—Lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½xROGï¿½ï¿½'<%#áˆŒFc2ï¿½Lï¿½vï¿½RJï¿½ï¿½xï¿½iï¿½ï¿½7ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½cï¿½ë¨ªï¿½Jmï¿½>bï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½0ï¿½ï¿½#*ï¿½0qï¿½ï¿½igï¿½ï¿½3:ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½lï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½9ï¿½ï¿½
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½G
8ï¿½ï¿½{ï¿½J����IENDï¿½B`ï¿½
```

So I did the below: base64 encode this and create an anchor tag with href and click it

=====

```
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
var base64String = btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
                          return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
                          }));
anchor.setAttribute("href", 'data:image/png;base64,'+ base64String);
anchor.setAttribute("download", "xx.png");
anchor.click();
```

====

However it still not giving me an image, any idea how can I process this response?

The image is 
[image]

Comment: where is the java input stream

Comment: the java spring server sent the above PNG as 

ResponseEntity.body(new InputStreamResource(x.getInputStream()));

Comment: It appears that it has extra byte at the start.. I did a unescape(encodeURIComponent(string_of_png))